# Cubic 3-edge connected graph has edge cover that can omit 2/3 of all edges over 5 graphs (so 2/15 per graph) and be 2-edge connected

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Let's assume that I have a cubic 3-edge connected simple graph $G$. After taking a perfect matching (and we can specify which one we want), I want to split the remaining edges in 5 sets $U_1, ..., U_5$ such that all $G-U_i$ is 2-edge connected.

For example, if I have a Peterson graph, I can take a perfect matching (in orange).

[image: Peterson graph with perfect matching]

Then, I can split the remaining edges in 5 sets (different colors).

[image: Peterson graph with edges split]

Notice how if I omit the edges in one of the $U_i$ (color blue for the picture below), then the graph is 2-edge connected. By symmetry, this works for all the sets that I've chosen, even though this won't be the case for all graphs.

[image: Peterson graph minus an Ei]

I've searched on the subject, but I've found nothing. I might just be searching for the wrong things though. Solving this would help with a problem I'm trying to find a good algorithm for. I need 5 different sets because I'm trying to achieve a certain ratio.

What I have found which was the closest is the following

> Let G be a bridgeless cubic graph with specified
>   edge e∗. Then there exists a 2-factor of G that covers all 3- and 4-edge cuts and does not contain e∗.
>
> (T. Kaiser and R. Skrekovski ˇ , Cycles intersecting edge-cuts of prescribed sizes, SIAM
>   J. Discrete Math., 22 (2008), pp. 861–874.)

While it may allow me to avoid the smaller cuts by requiring that all edges in a cut set not be of a same color, which would ensure 2-edge connectivity, I'm not sure how to show that.

Comment: @casteels I've edited the question to better explain what I'm trying to do. You were right in saying that my usage of "partition"was erroneous. Is this clearer?